# Conditional build in TFS CI

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration

I am planning to introduce gated checkins in TFS 2015 for our project. Our product consists of one database, one web service and one web front-end.
The database “build” and deploy take like 60 minutes. When that is done we generate C# source code for our Web service using meta data in the just deployed database.

We the build the Web server and start it.

Next step we generate C# source code for the Web front-end using the services in our running Web service.

Now, I would like to avoid building and deploying the database whenever possible. I other words I would like TFS to “ask me”, custom script of software” if the database should be built and deployed. This could be done using C# code, perl, python Windows batch file or other scripting/coding, exit code 1 is perform the build, exit code 0 don’t or whatever.

So, basically some feature in TFS that conditionally performs a build. I guess it could be two different builds, one with all steps and one with just Web service and Web frontend build. Please note that the database build is just a set of plain Windows batch files, two files to be precise.

Is this supported in some way?

Comment: Your builds should not be deploying software. A gated check-in exists to validate that the software builds successfully, passes static analysis rules, and that unit tests pass. Deployment is a separate process that should happen after the "gate" is passed.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but as you can see in my description above, we need to "deploy" before we can "build". The product is broken if the database and Web service builds but the Web frontend don't. So some form of deployment is a part of the total build.